# How to toggle the + - icon on click on the hamburger button

Tags: jquery

I have this code to control the menu/submenu. If i click the + icon to toggle the submenu, the - icon will be toggled.
But if i click the top ribbon/hamburger button so that the mobile menu and the submenu is closed, then if i click the 
hamburger button again the - icon is still there it should be the + icon. How can i do to get this to work?

Thank you.

[Menu Demo. Make window size about 800px](http://test3.fcab.se/responsive_menu_test/simple_multi_responsive_menu_flat/index.html)

```
// DOM ready
$(function() {

    // Add some classes and Append the mobile icon nav
    $('.nav').append($('<div class="nav-mobile"></div>'));
    $('.nav > ul').addClass('nav-list');
    $('.nav > ul > li').addClass('nav-item');
    $('.nav > ul > li > ul').addClass('nav-submenu');
    $('.nav > ul > li > ul > li').addClass('nav-submenu-item');

    // Add a <span> to every .nav-item that has a <ul> inside. And add an sub menu icon indicator.
    $('.nav-item').has('ul').prepend('<span class="nav-click"><i></i></span>');

    // Click to reveal the mobile menu
    $('.nav-mobile').click(function(){
    $('.nav-list').toggle();
    $('.nav-submenu').hide(); // This will close the submenu when i click the top ribbon (.nav-mobile) to close the mobile menu
    });

    // Dynamic binding to on 'click' and Toggle the nested nav
    $('.nav-list').on('click', '.nav-click', function(){
    $(this).siblings('.nav-submenu').toggle();

    // This will toggle the + and - when clicked
    $(this).removeClass('nav-click');
    $(this).toggleClass('icon-close');
    $(this).toggleClass('nav-click');

});
```

Comment: _toggle_ after _remove_ always add class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you'll most likely need to remove or toggle the `icon-close` class that you're adding when someone clicks a submenu item. Since you simply toggle the parent `nav-list` the internal items may not be closed either.

```
// Click to reveal the mobile menu
$('.nav-mobile').click(function(){
    $('.nav-list').toggle();
    $('.nav-submenu').hide(); // This will close the submenu when i click the top ribbon (.nav-mobile) to close the mobile menu
    if(!$('.nav-list').is(':visible')){ // the menu was closed because it's not visible anymore
        $('.nav-item .nav-click').each(function(){ //loop through nav clicks
            if($(this).hasClass('icon-close')) {
                $(this).toggleClass('icon-close');              
            }
        }); 
    }
});
```

I didn't test this code, but I think you'll get the idea :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i just tested this code but no luck.

Comment: Ohh, now it's working ihade to change this: $('.navitem .nav-click').each(function(){ //loop through nav clicks to this: $('.nav-item .nav-click').each(function(){ //loop through nav clicks. The .navitem was missing a hyphen. Thank you.

Comment: Hello again, I would also like it so that when i click the + icon to open a sub menu, if any other sub menu is opend then close it so that the only sub menu that is opend is the one i clicked. Thank you.

Comment: @PatrikIdén you can use a similar click function as mentioned above but instead of calling the function when the `.nav-mobile` is clicked, use whatever element you need. You might have to modify it a bit but the code I provided should give you a good starting point.

Comment: @PatrikIdén if you want to open another question and detail your attempt / exact problem I or someone else could help :)